# can i block zip files upload on server (godaddy linux shared hosting)?

Tags: security, ftp, godaddy

can i block zip files upload on server (godaddy linux shared hosting) ?

Acutally i have to provide ftp access to my employees and dont want them to upload zip or rar files.Can i prevent such uploads ?

Employees access net using proxy and i am thinking of software /browser plugin options to allow ftp access.

regards
sd

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but I thought you could use Squid to proxy FTP and then set rules within Squid to block specific ips, file names, etc.